# Is it a typo in the statement of this theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Consider the following theorem:

If $I$ is  a modular maximal ideal of a unital abelian algebra $A$, then $A/I$ is a field.

It is a basic fact of algebra that if $R$ is a commutative unital ring then $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal. A unital abelian algebra is a unital ring. So: is it possible that ''modular'' is a ''typo'' and can be ommited?

Just in case let me include the proof:

[image]

Comment: The "basic fact" should be with $\;R\;$ *commutative and unitary*.

Comment: I'm reading that the ideal $\;I\le R\;$ is *modular* iff there exists $\;e\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;re-r\in I\;\;\forall\,r\in R\;$ , which means $\;e+I\;$ is a (right) identity element in $\;R/I\;$ . This doesn't seem to have been used in the above proof, which I also don't understand why wasn't it stopped after "...the only ideals of $\;A/I\;$" ...